# Change from Theme Editor not showing OpenCart 3.0.2.0

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

I am new to OpenCart, upon searching I didn't find anything helpful.

The problem I am facing is that when I edit twig file from Theme editor It store change in DB but does not show on frontend. I have cleared cache as well.

It happens with my installed theme only. Default theme show changes.

But when I make change in file from cPanel. That's when it shows for my theme as well.

Let me know if I am missing anything here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your editor is saving files?
Perhaps he simply does not have enough records to write files.

Comment: @MykhailoYatzyshyn Yes files are being saved.

Answer (score 0):

did same happens when cache is turned off , try with turning off the cache.Sometimes its because of the modification cache when any changes are made to files, you always have to refresh the modification cache as-well

Present on dashboard

[image: present on dashboard]

present on extension, modification
  [image: present on extension, modification]

Comment: Okk,could you  please share some code view and tell which twig file you want to edit and what changes you are trying  to make,as of now more  specific detail is needed for further help.